# Converting values in a list to file names in Python

Tags: python, list

If I have a file that contains for example "foo bar" on one line, how could I convert that file into a list so I could open the foo file and bar file from it?

EDIT:
If I have a file called 'filenames' that contains the contents 'foo bar', how would I go from creating a list to opening the foo file, editing its contents and writing them to the bar file? This is what I've got so far.

```
import re

def main():   
    file = open('filenames.txt', 'r')
    text = file.read().lower()
    file.close()
    text = re.sub('[^a-z\ \']+', " ", text)
    words = list(text.split())

main()
```

Comment: Have you tried any code for this yet?

Comment: There's lots of ways to do this. Post some code you tried that doesn't work with the error message and ask how to get it working

Comment: What do you mean by opening the foo file and bar file from it? You mean `foo` is a folder and `bar` is a file inside it? Have you tried anything so far?

Answer (score 0):

here's one way to do it...

```
lst = list()
with open(myfile) as f:
    for line in f:
        lst.extend(line.split(" "))  # assuming words in line are split by single space
print lst  # or whatever you want to do with this list
```

Answer (score 0):

Opening file called `"filenames"`, reading the first line and getting the names of the `source` file to read and `target` file to write:

```
with open("filenames", 'r') as f:
        # Read contents on file:
        text = f.readline()
        source = text.split(" ")[0]
        target = text.split(" ")[1]
```

Now, with the following code you can read the source file, do stuff and write it to the target file:

```
with open(source, 'r') as s:
        # Read contents on file:
        source_text = s.read()

        # Do stuff with source text here

        # Now, let's write it to the target file:
        with open(target, 'w') as t:
            t.write('stuff to write goes here')
```

And that's all.

For more information on reading and writing files, read the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).

Comment: Thanks so much, got it to work no problem. I want to be able to open the target file after to show that the new data did write to it but I can't seem to get that to work either. Any clue as how I could do that too? I've tried update = open(target, "r"), print(update) but it won't work.

Comment: To read the contents of a file, you must use the function `read()` after opening it. More info is available in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html).